# Javascript Cookie mobile detect

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

i detect if somebody is using a mobile device or tablet.
Now i don't want the user to get the alert everytime he visits the page.
How can i implement cookies into the code. I used one but it didn't work.
Maybe some of you could help me.

```
var isMobile = /iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
document.cookie = "testcookie";
if (isMobile) {
    window.alert("Please visit on a Desktop PC to get the full experience!")
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: ``document.cookie = "devicename=testcookie";`` you are missing the cookie name, without cookie name you cannot access it, where **devicename**  is the cookie name

Comment: Now coming to the problem, first check if your cookie exist or not, if not then create the cookies depending upon the device you are targeting, and then if exist then fetch the cookie and process accordingly you like.